# Aerospike Cluster configuration

Tags: database, docker, aerospike

I try to get an Aerospike Cluster up and running through Docker and use the following config to get my cluster up

```
Configuration:
    service {
            user root
            group root
            paxos-single-replica-limit 1 # Number of nodes where the replica count is automatically reduced to 1.
            pidfile /var/run/aerospike/asd.pid
            service-threads 24
            transaction-queues 4
            transaction-threads-per-queue 4
            proto-fd-max 15000

    }



    network {
        service {
            address any
            access-address 172.16.43.5
            port 3000
        }

        heartbeat {
            mode mesh

            port 3002 # Heartbeat port for this node.
            address 172.16.43.5
            # List one or more other nodes, one ip-address & port per line:
            # Please note that we do not have the address of the incoming node in this list
            mesh-seed-address-port 172.16.43.7  3002
            mesh-seed-address-port 172.16.43.5  3002
            # Having the node itself as a mesh seed node is allowed
            # and helps with consistent configuration files across the cluster

            interval 250
            timeout 10
        }

        fabric {
            port 3001
        }

        info {
            port 3003
        }
    }

    namespace test {
                                   # Data in memory without persistance namespace
        replication-factor 2
        memory-size 32G
        default-ttl 30d               # 30 days, use 0 to never expire/evict.
        storage-engine memory
    }
```

But the Node in the Cluster fails with the following error:

`Mar 22 2019 16:48:48 GMT: WARNING (socket): (socket.c:805) Error while binding to 172.16.43.5:3002: 99 (Cannot assign requested address)`

this is the command I try to run it with:

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 -p 3002:3002 -p 9918:9918 -v /home/user/aerospike:/opt/aerospike/etc aerospike/aerospike-server:latest --config-file /opt/aerospike/etc/aerospike.conf
```

If using `--net host` I get the following error:
`cat: /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate: No such file or directory`

Is that kind of a bug or am I missconfigurating something?

Comment: can you share your docker run command? Altry binding the address to interface name for the heartbeat (ie: address eth0 or address ens3,...)

Comment: I did, thanks! where exactly should i add the address?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the aerospike dockerimage.
the name of the network device is hardcoded in entrypoint.sh

so for me it was fixed by changing the line `NETLINK=${NETLINK:-eth0}`
to `NETLINK=${NETLINK:-eno1}`